# How to install .exe file on Ubuntu without using Wine?

Tags: 12.04

I have a Matlab installation file in .exe format.

Is it possible to install Matlab on Ubuntu without using Wine?

Comment: no you can not do that (run the .exe in Ubuntu) without wine or software compatibility layer.. (or other emulator/simulator apps to run some .exes) ...and like Oli suggests you could try the linux version or [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072884/whats-the-best-matlab-equivalent-open-source-or-otherwise-free)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Linux version of MATLAB. [Installing it is fairly simple](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB).

What you have (the .exe) is an installer for the Windows version. Even if you could run it without Wine, its contents are for Windows, not Ubuntu. It's not going to work.

With Wine, it [should be possible to get this working](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=49), but it's very likely going to be slower than a native install. If you're doing big things, that's going to be a real disadvantage.

I'd focus on getting hold of the right version. For MATLAB it appears the same license to any platform so if you have one, it should be possible (I'm not sure how feasible this will be in practise) to get hold of the right installer. [Talk to MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus) or your supplier and see if they can help.

Answer (score -1):

If its Mono-compatable then...Maybe

But Wine is Really your best shot at getting ANYTHING windows related to work under linux